# TFS Web Deploy doesn't execute via Build but executes locally?

Tags: deployment, tfs, msbuild, msdeploy

I have a solution that I am trying to get TFS 2010 to deploy after it builds.

When I run the following msbuild command locally, it deploys fine:

`msbuild C:\Path\to\Solution.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:MSDeployServiceUrl=https://[Server]:8172/MsDeploy.axd /p:DeployIisAppPath="TestSite" /p:UserName=Domain\Username /p:Password=NotTheRealPassword /P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True`

However, when I stick those same options into the TFS 2010 build MS Build arguments:

[image]

...it doesn't appear to execute anything.

The build finishes correctly:

[image]

But I see nothing in the entire log file related to deployment, etc. It's as if the parameters were never even passed in to MSBuild from TFS.

### The MSBuild Command Being Called by TFS

The log has it as (scrubbed sensitive data): `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /nologo /noconsolelogger "C:\Builds\1\[Scrubbed]\Daily6am\Sources\[Scrubbed].sln" /m:1 /fl /flp:"logfile=C:\Builds\1\[Scrubbed]\[Scrubbed]\Sources\[Scrubbed].log;encoding=Unicode;verbosity=normal" /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:MSDeployServiceUrl=https://[Scrubbed]:8172/MsDeploy.axd /p:DeployIisAppPath="TestSite" /p:UserName=[Scrubbed]\farmservice /p:Password=[Scrubbed] /p:AllowUntrusted=True /P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:OutDir="C:\Builds\1\[Scrubbed]\[Scrubbed]\Binaries\\" /p:Configuration="Debug" /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:VCBuildOverride="C:\Builds\1\[Scrubbed]\[Scrubbed]\Sources\[Scrubbed].sln.Any CPU.Debug.vsprops"  /dl:WorkflowCentralLogger,"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Normal;BuildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/23;InformationNodeId=4504;TargetsNotLogged=GetNativeManifest,GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems,GetTargetPath;TFSUrl=http://[Scrubbed]:8080/tfs/[Scrubbed]_Collection;"*WorkflowForwardingLogger,"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Normal;"`

### Questions

- How can I get TFS to tell MSBuild to build the deployment?
- How can I verify whether the parameters were even passed in?
- How can I correctly read the logs to know if this has taken place or not?

Assistance on any of these would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try changing the deployment URL to a bogus address and see if you _still_ see nothing in the log.

Comment: Hi John -- see my answer below. Just a few minutes ahead of you, but it's what solved it for me.

Comment: I saw your answer, but wanted to know whether something shows in the log if you use a bogus URL.

Comment: Oh I see -- sorry, I didn't understand. I'll check a little later today with a new build and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the answer on a SO question from a bit ago :)

According to the answer at [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644635/how-to-determine-if-msbuild-arguments-were-executed-for-tfs-build-definition?rq=1), [@marvc1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999337/marvc1) (credit where it's due) suggested copying the following files:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications`

I had copied WebApplications, but not Web. Copying web resolved the issue.