# MSBuild not triggering WebDeploy on Wndows Server 2012 R2

Tags: iis, msbuild, webdeploy, windows-server-2012-r2

In my development machine I can successfully deploy from Visual Studio 2015 to IIS 8.5 installed on Windows Server 2012 on my local network.

```
msbuild projectname.csproj  
/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 
/p:DeployOnBuild=true 
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://myserver:8172/msdeploy.axd 
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 
/p:DeployIisAppPath=projectname 
/p:Username=tc 
/p:Password=pass
```

On my Windows Server I have installed **msbuild**, **webdeploy** and **webdeploy for hosting services**.
However, running the same command results in:

```
0 errors
1 warning (...Conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly...) 
Build succeeded
```

And it doesn’t continue to deploy, no errors , no messages.

Do I have to resolve the warning message for msbuild to deploy or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Microsoft for such a great verbose mode of this tool that **says absolutely nothing** when I tell it to deploy!!!

The solutions is here:[MSBuild not triggering WebDeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640707/msbuild-not-triggering-webdeploy)

It requires both folders to be present on the server:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications
>
> C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web

I was missing the second one (facepalm).